# Java 8 JDK is installed but installing BlueJ fails

Tags: java, java-8, bluej

I'm using linux OS with Debian 11 distribution. I'm using this [this documentation](https://www.dukelearntoprogram.com//downloads/bluej.php?course=2).

The output of `javac -version` is  `javac 1.8.0_371` indicating that **I have Java 8 JDK installed**.

I downloaded the specific version of BlueJ mentioned in the documentation. Then I ran `sudo dpkg -i BlueJ-linux-411-duke.deb` and it outputs this error messages:

```
Selecting previously unselected package bluej.
(Reading database ... 205849 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack BlueJ-linux-411-duke.deb ...
Unpacking bluej (4.1.1-duke) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bluej:
 bluej depends on openjdk-8-jdk | oracle-java8-jdk | oracle-java8-installer; however:
  Package openjdk-8-jdk is not installed.
  Package oracle-java8-jdk is not installed.
  Package oracle-java8-installer is not installed.
 bluej depends on libopenjfx-java | oracle-java8-jdk | oracle-java8-installer; however:
  Package libopenjfx-java is not installed.
  Package oracle-java8-jdk is not installed.
  Package oracle-java8-installer is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package bluej (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.69) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bluej
```

It's saying things like `Package oracle-java8-jdk is not installed.` even though it is certainly installed.

I'm completely new to Java. Any feedback, help, and answers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you set PATH environment variable properly? https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html

Comment: @Rafael yes I have, Here's how I did it:                                                                                `sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_371/bin/java" 0`                                                                                              -                                                                                      
`sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_371/bin/javac" 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now solved this problem by running

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then in the sources.list file I added this:

```
deb https://debian.opennms.org/ stable main
```

Then I run this commands in order:

```
wget -O - http://debian.opennms.org/OPENNMS-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -



sudo apt-get update



sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer



sudo dpkg -i BlueJ-linux-411-duke.deb
```

I now have BlueJ installed and can run it.